# It is possible to get that captcha image?

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I am wondering if it is possible to obtain captcha image from site using web request. The thing is, that this captcha image is changing every time I refresh the page, for example:
http://zapytaj.onet.pl/captcha/obrazek.jpg?6165303

As you can notice, if you refresh the page url stays the same, but the code is changed.

The implementation of captcha code on page is:

```
            <img id="captcha-image" src="/captcha/obrazek.jpg?5842454"/>
<div>
   Complete captcha (<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#captcha-image').attr('src', '/captcha/obrazek.jpg?' + (Date.now() / 1000 | 0))">Refresh</a>)
    <input type="text" name="captcha_code" class="text">
```

Url link to every captcha is changing every time I refresh to. So even if I get the captcha url it will not work, because the image is randomly generated.

I managed something like this:

```
Dim dt1970 As DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
Dim current As Date = DateTime.Now
Dim span As TimeSpan = current - dt1970

Dim requestUriString As String = "http://zapytaj.onet.pl/captcha/obrazek.jpg?" + (Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.Now) / span.TotalMilliseconds).ToString() + ""
Dim httpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(requestUriString), HttpWebRequest)
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = Me.cookieJar(4)
Dim httpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim image As Image = Image.FromStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
httpWebResponse.Close()
Me.PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
Me.PictureBox1.Image = image
```

I should also add the bitwise AND operation, but I think that would not work anyway. I think because of differences in `DateTime` values between my app and website.

If I take only the `http://zapytaj.onet.pl/captcha/obrazek.jpg` as `requestUriString` I got the captcha image, but as I said its not that one.

The url with captcha image:
http://zapytaj.onet.pl/register.html#register-email-form

Comment: The number after the `?` is likely just a 'cache buster' - designed to affect how a browser will *cache* an image but it has *no bearing* on the generated image itself. If I was writing the captcha it would change on each request, always and it would be different each request. (The caching is an aspect of the web-browser; HttpWebRequest does not have built-in caching.)

Comment: Hmm so it is possible, or not?

Comment: It's possible to be *an* image. Yes. Is it possible to get the *same* image on different requests? Not (and/or hopefully not) by making another HTTP request.